# ImageView doesn't display images

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, imageview

I want to swipe through 3 images inside an `ImageView` which is inflated in a `ViewPager` when I run my application, I can swipe through 3 blank pages/images, no image is displayed. 
The images are inside the `res/drawable` folder.

I have tried to add every line of code proposed here on stack overflow as I've looked through all posts related to this matter (you will see them all in the code that I will provide.
I have tried to resize the images down to 300x300 but it still doesn't work.
I tried putting the images inside a sub-folder of the drawable folder, or inside the `hdpi, mdpi,xdpi...`etc folder, a compilation error occurs.

1)xml file of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="480dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible"> </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>


</RelativeLayout>
```

2)custom_layout code (imageView):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

3) whole ViewPagerAdapter:

```
package com.example.apptest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.resized1, R.drawable.resized2, R.drawable.resized3};

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem( ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
        ImageView imageView =  view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);            
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }



    @Override
    public void destroyItem( ViewGroup container, int position,  Object object) {
        ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
        View view = (View) object;
        vp.removeView((View)view);

    }
```

}

4) android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.apptest">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".menuSliderActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

5) java code of the activity:

```
package com.example.apptest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

public class menuSliderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu_slider);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }
```

}

I should normally be able to see my images and swipe through them, but instead, I don't get any errors, and the page is blank.

Comment: how do you instantiate "images"?

Comment: Your `image resource` has nothing to do with the `image[position]`

Comment: @haythemsouissi I posted the function in the post, please take a look at it.

Comment: @StavroXhardha what do you suggest? I'm a beginner in Android Studio and Java.

Comment: image[position] is returning R.drawable.your_image ?

Comment: Please, are more code (activity and layout), it's not clear with just these lines

Comment: what does the `image[position]` return?

Comment: Since you're referencing them as `@mipmap/ic_launcher` shouldn't they be put in the folder "res/mipmap" rather than "res/drawable"?

Comment: @andygeers i tried to put them in mipmap/mpdi or mipmap/hdpi...etc but i get compiling errors.

Comment: you can put it on drawable or mipmap this is not a problem, you just need to instantiate your object images
images = [R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ...]

Comment: @YasmineGuemouria I think I'd try putting a normal .png in res/drawable and see if you can get that working (@drawable/file) - if that works then you know the mipmaps is the issue

Comment: Please, share your complete `ViewPager` adapter.

Comment: @haythemsouissi that's exactly what i did, please look at the code.

Comment: in the code you didn't put how do you instantiate images

Comment: @haythemsouissi very sorry, I just edited my post, here's the whole Adapter file. thank you.

Comment: can you try int[] imgs = { R.id.draw_1, R.id.draw_2, R.id.draw_3, R.id.draw_4 };

int instead of Integer

Comment: I think the answer you have accepted is not the correct one.;)

Comment: @Ferran yes you're right hahaha I made a mistake thank you for correcting me. Both your answer and Ugas's are the same. Can't I accept 2 questions? :(

Comment: No, only one but @Ugas sent it just before me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is working me perfectly

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View)object);
}
```

instead of this

```
 @Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem( ViewGroup container, int position,  Object object) {
    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView((View)view);

}
```

Comment: I tried this (the " return view.equals(object);") in the morning and it returned me an error, now it works like a charm! maybe one of the lines of codes i've changed throughout the day have made it work now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this test

Replace wrap_content to match_parent

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: i tried it, it doesn't change anything. thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this

```
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
    return view == o;
}
```